# Send hook preprocess_views_view results to custom form or services

Tags: views, forms, hooks

I am developing a feature that allows anonymous users to receive by email the result of a [facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) + [searchAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

Facets and Search API work perfectly. The custom module that allows to send an email too. I have also created a custom form (FormAPi) to let user gives its mail and send the datas on submit.

To get the results of the facets search, I use the `preprocess_views_view` in `.module` file

```
function my_module_preprocess_views_view__VIEW_ID(array &$variables): void {
  foreach ($variables['view']->result as $result) {
    $node = $result->_object->getEntity();
    $title = $node->get('title')->getValue()[0]['value'];
    $custom_field = $node->get('custom_field')->getValue()[0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Every time a facet is modified, I can see the result with a `dump()` and everything is ok. Maybe this is not the right hook in my case but it returns what I expect.

However, I don't know how to pass the result of this hook to my custom form which is inserted in a custom block on the page with the facets results view.

When the user submits the form, I need to know what the hook previously returned in SendSearchForm()

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        // email entered by user
        $email = $form_state->getValue('email');
        // send email but need to send also my_module_preprocess_views_view__VIEW_ID results
        $this->sendEmail($email, $facets_result);
    }
```

Do you have a suggestion to do this properly with Drupal?

EDIT : I've seen than I could use `function drupal_static`. Is it a good idea ?

Comment: This is not what preprocess hooks are for (calling and commuicating to other functions/methods). All you can do is set a config variable or cache item to store this, but it likely won't be accurate 100% of the time because you don't have many ways to tell one anonymous user from the other. Maybe store it in user temp store.. not sure.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I also realize that hooks not for that. Since the hook returned exactly what I wanted, I tried to use it but I have to figure something else out. Maybe programmatically run the search performed by the user by retrieving the parameters at the time of form submit.

Comment: @Kevin I managed to do what I wanted by fetching the selection in javascript. I think I will delete the question because the topic is no longer relevant.